# Schedule a function do something even on a loop function

Tags: android-studio

Hey I'm thinking of a code that triggers a function every 1 minute but in a loop function, every time I do this it schedule the function run 55555 times none stop and do them in the same time all of them

What I want to do is to make it do it every 1 minute only once even on a loop function as onGpsStatusChanged or location listener

Android studio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use Android `JobScheduler` for this purpose. This implementation will help you to post action at specific time, of with timeouts. Read [more from the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler).

.
.

2. Another and probably post simple way to do it, it's using Android `Handler` and post delay function. For ex.

   ```
   private static final long DELAY = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)

   private void startTask() {
      new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
             /**
              * Your function here, and start task again!
              */
              startTask()
          }

      }, DELAY);
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm using android studio java I'm not sure about val

Comment: @Calli I have changed to `Java`.

Comment: Thank you!
Bro, I think it's doing every 1 second twice i want it to make sure it does it only once every 1 second

Comment: Its a bug with my function I'm calling it in, but the problem I don't have any function else this with the bug to trigger it

Comment: And it raises its speed after some minutes or some time it raise the speed of the function start task to do it every second 5 times and wait for some it do it every second 10 and go on no stop

Comment: @Calli past code, how you are doing it. Above implementation is correct.

Comment: Okay correct me i'm not so sure, I'm calling the startTask() on a function that loop every second the same startTask()

Comment: @Calli Yup. You are doing wrong. You need to call it once only. It will restart automatically every minute.

Comment: I know that's why I asked a question I think my question wasn't clear sorry 
I have a class that only have functions that will repeat so I'm trying to force it be only once

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean so could you post code? Anyway I use this to run `timerTick` every minute ...

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                timerTick();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * 60);
            }
        };
        this.runOnUiThread(r);
```

Comment: Hey every time I do this on a loop function as onGpsStatusChanged something that always running it repeat the function you give me so fast and none stop I'm trying to force it to repeat 1 time every 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

> triggers a function every 1 minute but in a loop function, every time
>   I do this it schedule the function run 55555 times none stop and do
>   them in the same time all of them

I would also use either the **JobScheduler** or **TimerTick**  on *Android* Studio.

```
final val TIME_PERIOD = TimeUnit.Milliseconds(60000)

try {
   scheduleMethod() {
     Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
       Runnable {
         execute()
       }, TIME_PERIOD)
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm using android studio java
I'm not sure about val